# What's the difference between tracking branch and upstream branch in git?

Tags: git

Or what's the different between those two commands? What does "tracking" refer to? How about "upstream"? Are the two actions different?

```
git branch --track [branch] [remote-branch]  
git branch --set-upstream [branch] [remote-branch]
```

thx~

Comment: Please spell check your question title. Also the body while you're at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind both commands is that you'd like to track the changes in a remote branch.

```
git branch --track [branch] [remote-branch]
```

Creates a local branch from the remote-branch and sets the remote-branch as its upstream in order to track differences. This is the default behavior when branching off of a remote branch and can be controlled using the branch.autoSetupMerge configuration variable.

```
git branch --set-upstream [branch] [remote-branch]
```

Updates the upstream branch of a local branch to track differences to the remote-branch. If the local branch didn't yet exist, the above two commands would be equivalent. The main difference is that --set-upstream doesn't necessarily modify the branch pointer.

For further information, you should review the [git branch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).